# Is there a way to get a QTP to fail a test if a particular element appears on a web page

Tags: testing, vbscript, qtp

I am trying to test a JSP based web application with QTP. On some of the pages the JSP is coded to return a particular **div** element, which will have an ID attribute, to the browser, only of the underlying model has a certain boolean flag set. I'd like to be able to develop a QTP test that fails if the **div** is present in the returned web page. However, the QTP documentation doesn't seem to have any details on how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is to detect if the condition applies and then explicitly fail the test.

```
If Browser("b").Page("p").WebElement("html tag:=div", "html id:=theId").Exist Then
    ''# Report failure 
    Reporter.ReportEvent micFail, "Element Exists", "It shouldn't"
    ''# if you also want to stop the test
    ExitTest
End If
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked with 2 small changes: 'id:' should have been 'html id:' and 'Exists' should have been 'Exist'.

Answer (score 1):

The **default behavior** for QTP is to write in 'Report' when a check point fails. i.e. if an element is not found on the page , automatically the QTP will write in the log report. In order to disable that , and to **customize your report** depending on your test scenarios, you can disable the report logging from the 
beginning and write only in case you found an abnormal behavior.

Reporter.Filter = rfDisableAll 
'check point validations
Reporter.Filter = rfEnableAll